# Can anyone please tell me in which language the below mentioned code is written. The file is named as xxxx.tpl

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, oxid

```
<div id="c-content">       
            <div id="list-wrap">
              <h1 class="pageHead">[{$search_head}]</h1>
                [{block name="search_results"}]
                [{if $oView->getArticleCount() }]
                  <div class="listRefine clear bottomRound">
                      [{block name="search_top_listlocator"}]
                      [{include file="widget/locator/listlocator.tpl"  locator=$oView->getPageNavigationLimitedTop() listDisplayType=true itemsPerPage=true sort=true }]
                      [{/block}]
                  </div>
                [{else}]
                  <div>[{ oxmultilang ident="PAGE_SEARCH_SEARCH_NOITEMSFOUND" }]</div>
                [{/if}]
                [{if $oView->getArticleList() }]
                  [{foreach from=$oView->getArticleList() name=search item=product}]
                    [{include file="widget/product/list.tpl" type=$oView->getListDisplayType() listId="searchList" products=$oView->getArticleList() showMainLink=true }]
                  [{/foreach}]
                [{/if}]
                [{if $oView->getArticleCount() }]
                  [{include file="widget/locator/listlocator.tpl" locator=$oView->getPageNavigationLimitedBottom() place="bottom"}]
                [{/if}]
                [{/block}]
              [{ insert name="oxid_tracker" title=$template_title }]

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.tpl files are used in smarty, its a template system.

You can check details on www.smarty.net

Answer (score 2):

HTML + Smarty V2 with custom delimiters [{...}]  instead of regular smarty delimiters {...}

Comment: can I use pure php code in these files?

Comment: yes, you have to enable parsing php code in templates (somewhere in general shop settings) and then you can use php code this way: [{php}] echo "hello"; [{/php}] but most people would tell you not to use raw php in templates.